# electron how to redirect data from node to angular 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

I generated an Angular 7 application, which is running at http://localhost:4200
I have an application in Node JS that is responsible for authenticating the user on Facebook, running at http://localhost:3000

there the callback redirection works correctly

**index.js (node)**

```
//facebook
const FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'xxx';
const FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'xxx';

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback"
},
function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
  return cb(null, profile, accessToken);
}
));

app.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'));


app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:4200/login'
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/main' + req.authInfo);
  });

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server en port ${port}`)
});
```

**app.modules.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'main/:token',
    component: MainComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: Error404Component
  },
];
```

**main.js (electron)**

```
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  Menu,
  dialog
} = require('electron');
const openAboutWindow = require('about-window').default;

let win;
let menu;

const application_menu = [{
    label: 'Archivo',
    submenu: [{
      label: 'Salir',
      accelerator: 'Command+Q',
      click: () => {
        app.quit();
      }
    }, ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Configuración',
    submenu: [{
      label: 'Carpetas',
      accelerator: 'CommandOrControl+o',
      click: () => {
        openFolderDialog()
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    label: 'Ayuda',
    submenu: [{
        label: 'Documentación',
        click() {
          require('electron').shell.openExternal('https://electronjs.org')
        }
      },
    ]
  }
];


function createWindow() {
  let nd = require('./api/index.js');

  menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(application_menu);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    show: false,
    icon: __dirname + '/icons/batman.ico'
  });

  win.loadFile('./dist/UI/index.html');

  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.show()
  })

  win.on('closed', function () {
    win = null;
  });
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
});
```

When trying to include it in Electron, I can invoke the node functions, but I can not redirect the data to angular

I tried with file: /// and it does not work either, it does not give error either

I appreciate your help

Comment: How are you displaying angular content in electron? Can you add a sample? Are you using a webview? Or you integrating angular into electron?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must return JSON response and make decision in electron app based on JSON , whether the authorization has passed or not. Because the starting point of the angular and that serves it is electron app, and i think you can't redirect this way.

Comment: **CORS request external redirect not allowed**
The CORS request was responded to by the server with an HTTP redirect to a URL on a different origin than the original request, which is not permitted during CORS requests. To fix the problem, update your code to use the new URL as reported by the redirect, thereby avoiding the redirect. [Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSExternalRedirectNotAllowed)